# Getting Request failed with status 403: undefined on snack.expo.io

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-native, expo

I am developing an app with react native on SNACK.EXPO.IO.

After some days without touching the code, a mistake appeared when I ran the app on my device :

```
Device: (895:881) Request failed with status 403: undefined
Evaluating module://@react-navigation/bottom-tabs.js
Evaluating module://App.js.js
Loading module://App.js
```

I don't understand where it can come from..

Is someone able to help me??

[image: Screenshot of the issue]

Comment: I think there is not sufficient information to help you. Can you provide a minimal example of code that describes the issue more precisely?

Comment: Same here. The code worked, and 5min after it started this error. Did you figure it out?